# Redirect to shared Error view from Global.asax on MVC unhandled exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I've been reading about the different ways to perform error handling in ASP.MVC.  I know about `try/catch` within a controller, and also about `[HandleError]` at controller-level.

However, I am trying to perform global error handling for unhandled exceptions that could occur **anywhere** in the application (the *wow - we never expected a user to do that!* type of thing).  The result of this is that an email is sent to dev's:

This is working fine:

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    Exception last_ex = Server.GetLastError();
    Server.ClearError();
    // send email here...
    Response.Redirect("/Login/Login");
}
```

Elsewhere in the application, should an error occur in a controller, we have this logic which provides a friendly error in our error view:

**Error Model**

```
namespace My.Models
{
    public class ErrorViewModel
    {
        public string Summary { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller Code**

```
if(somethingBad){
    return View("Error", new ErrorViewModel { Summary = "Summary here", Description = "Detail here" });
}
```

My question is, is it possible to redirect to the error view passing the `ErrorViewModel` from within Global.asax, e.g.

```
// send email here...
Response.MethodToGetToView(new ErrorViewModel { Summary = "Error", Description = ex.Message });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Application_Error method, you can do something like:

```
RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
routeData.Values.Add("action","Error500");
routeData.Values.Add("Summary","Error");
routeData.Values.Add("Description", ex.Message);
IController controller = new ErrorController()
controller.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
```

This will return the view from the action result you specify here to the user's browser, so you will need a controller & action result that returns your desired error view (Error/Error500 in this example). It is not a redirect so is technically more correct (if an error occurs, you should return an HTTP 500 status immediately, not a 302 then a 500 as is often done).

Also, if you want to capture all 404's from all URLs (not just those that match a route), you can add the following route to the end of your route config

```
routes.MapRoute("CatchAllUrls", "{*url}", new { controller = "Error", action = "Error404" }, new string[] { "MyApp.Controllers" });
```

Comment: So you're saying that you cannot use a `View` directly, but must create an `ErrorController` first and use that within `routeData`?

Comment: Yes, that's right - you need to create an instance of the controller to return the view at this point.

Comment: Alternatively you can use a 'Response.Redirect' but you'd still need the controller action result, and you'd have to querystring your model values